# populating html two tier div table with dynamic data

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a table like this .  . :

```
    <h3>Testing</h3>
<div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong></strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead" ng-repeat="entype in EnvironmentTypes"><span style="font-weight: bold;" >{{entype.Name}}</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow" ng-repeat="type in TestingTypes">
        <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">{{type.Name}}</span></div>
        <div class="rTableCell" ng-repeat="item in EnvironmentTypes" alue="0"><input type="text" ng-bind="getResult(entype,type)"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

From a get method i get values from the database and store it in a scope variable..

```
releaseService.getTestingbyRelease(id).then(function (info) {
       if (info !== undefined) {
                 $scope.Testing = info;

       }
 }).catch(function (exception) {
         console.error(exception);
 });
```

$scope.Testing has a array with testing type id (the headers that go down) and id for environment.

I need to fill the textboxes in the table with the right value by checking the top and side header. I dont know if this makes sense .. but the plunker for what i have is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jcGcL1nLN7K8vRkC2q3O?p=preview)

Ive tried adding a ng-bind function to check the iteration value ids and assign the value but it doesnt work. Write now the Testing array has one record which has TestingTypeId : 1 and EnvironmentId: 1. So in the table the first cell under Dev/QE should be filled.

How should i  make this work?